# Which is the best Technology in .net? For web development

Tags: .net

I am new in .net; I would like to learn any new technology in .net. Prefer me any good technology to develop web application effectively and easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you're new I strongly suggest you start learning the absolute basics first: whatever *language* you're using, IO, collections etc. I'd then learn LINQ to Objects as a way of making in-memory collection handling more pleasant.

Then (and only then) start looking at web applications - [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) is very popular at the moment.

If your application is going to use a database then at some point you'll want to pick one of the myriad data access APIs - Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL, SubSonic, nHibernate, straight ADO.NET etc.

Comment: For a lot of basic asp.net development you could probably get about without the IO namespace.

Answer (score 5):

.NET has lots of different technologies.

For web development there are ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC.

You can find more information on http://www.asp.net/

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you Silverlight, MVVM pattern and RIA Services (plus Entity Framework). If you start, start learning most recent tecnologies:)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you MVC and ASP.net, IF take MVC its a language collection.(not only MVC) so learn

```
 1. JQuery 
 2. Javascript      
 3. CSS  
 4. 3rd party opensource tools  
 5. paid tools  
 6. Entity Framework method  
 7. 3tire Architechure  
 8. html5
```

because MNC company prefer the 3rd party tools